# Any comments on prior art for File system interface for CIM (us8458236)?

Tags: us8458236

Seems like there's some pretty clear prior art here:

http://pdf.aminer.org/000/642/555/odefs_a_file_system_interface_to_an_object_oriented_database.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. I'd like to provide some information about the site. We have a big template for prior art questions. It may be overkill in some cases and you do not need to use the template to post a question, but like all SE sites we would like questions and answers to be self contained enough that following a link is not required. Pasting in a representative claim from the patent in question would go a long way to improving this question. Also, not to be overly pedantic but, like other SE sites we try not to mix a question and an answer in a single post.

Comment: At a quick look, I do not think there is clear prior art in that paper. The Bell Labs paper is about putting a conventional file system view on an object oriented database. The patent cited is almost the converse. It puts an object oriented view on a conventional file system.

Comment: Definitely should have used the form. I disagree on your characterization of the '36 patent, though: "An embodiment of a method receives file operation commands through a client interface and performs CIM functions corresponding to the received file operation commands based on a mapping of the file operation commands to the CIM functions." CIM is basically an object-oriented database...